# What is the best way to handle collision detection between bodies efficiently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, box2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2d, Box2d and game development all together, but I have read a good bit of tutorials to at least have a good start on a game set up and working...

Im now at the point where I need to start adding more bodies to a layer and need to check and see if and when my main avatar will collide with any of them..

Common sense seems to tell me that the more bodies I add and the more cases I add checking to see if fixture1 is colliding with fixture2 for instance will bog down the processor at some point..

Are there any best practices and/or efficient algorithms to make these checks more efficient over time as the number of bodies grow?

Any links or direction would be appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuadTree to divide the scene and get a list of bodies that needs to be checked.
(There are a lot of articles shows how QuadTree works, just google it:D )

And if that's a little complex for you. Then you can try to divide your scene into many grid, and make a loop to put bodies in their grid based on their 2d position. Then just check bodies in each grid. It's a lot faster than normal loop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5cBT.png

Comment: thank you! ill check those out! I think after rereading my post, I realized that I know box2d does the collision detection for you for the most part, the part Im questioning is that once a collision is detected, is checking the 2 UNKNOWN fixtures with every fixture in the scene really the best way to figure out what you collided with and where it occured?

Comment: It depends on the amount of your fixture. When it's small, like 0-10, that's the best solution. When it's a lot more, use some algorithms to decrease the cpu usage. And actually i haven't used box2d before, so i can't show you some code about this. Hope someone else can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7 you can use Sprite Kit to handle collisions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14